# How to use EF Core with Azure SQL Shards for .NET 5+?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, azure-sql-database, azure-elastic-sharding

We have a SaaS product with customer tenants, and we are trying to implement scalable database access, but it looks like the ElasticScale github project has been abandoned. Is there a new mechanism for this? How do you implement scalable, manageable database shards in a modern version of EF?

Comment: I have the same exact problem/question. Were you able to find an answer/solution/suggestion?

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible and works great with EF Core using interceptors:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/logging-events-diagnostics/interceptors

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;
using System.Data.Common;

namespace <blah>;

public class RowLevelSecuritySqlInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor, IRowLevelSecuritySqlInterceptor
{
    public Guid? TenantId { get; set; }

    public override InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result)
    {
        SetSessionContext(command);

        return base.ReaderExecuting(command, eventData, result);
    }

    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<DbDataReader>> ReaderExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<DbDataReader> result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new ())
    {
        SetSessionContext(command);

        return base.ReaderExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override InterceptionResult<int> NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result)
    {
        SetSessionContext(command);

        return base.NonQueryExecuting(command, eventData, result);
    }

    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<int>> NonQueryExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<int> result, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new ())
    {
        SetSessionContext(command);

        return base.NonQueryExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }

    public override InterceptionResult<object> ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<object> result)
    {
        SetSessionContext(command);

        return base.ScalarExecuting(command, eventData, result);
    }
    public override ValueTask<InterceptionResult<object>> ScalarExecutingAsync(DbCommand command, CommandEventData eventData, InterceptionResult<object> result,
        CancellationToken cancellationToken = new ())
    {
        SetSessionContext(command);

        return base.ScalarExecutingAsync(command, eventData, result, cancellationToken);
    }

    private void SetSessionContext(IDbCommand command)
    {
        var tenantId = TenantId is null ? "null" : $"'{TenantId.Value}'";
        command.CommandText = $"EXEC sp_set_session_context @key=N'TenantId', @value={tenantId};" + command.CommandText;
    }
}
```

You can create an interface for DI:

```
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Diagnostics;

namespace <blah>;

public interface IRowLevelSecuritySqlInterceptor : IDbCommandInterceptor
{
    Guid? TenantId { get; set; }
}
```

And inject it to the DI container:

```
services.TryAddTransient<IRowLevelSecuritySqlInterceptor, RowLevelSecuritySqlInterceptor>();
```

And your DbContext may look something like:

```
public partial class MyDbContext
{
    private readonly IRowLevelSecuritySqlInterceptor _rowLevelSecuritySqlInterceptor;
    ...

    public AccountServiceDbContext(
        ...,
        IRowLevelSecuritySqlInterceptor rowLevelSecuritySqlInterceptor) : base(options)
    {
        ...,
        _rowLevelSecuritySqlInterceptor = rowLevelSecuritySqlInterceptor;
    }

    ...

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        optionsBuilder
            .UseSqlServer(...)
            .AddInterceptors(_rowLevelSecuritySqlInterceptor, ... and other interceptors);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The package `Microsoft.Azure.SqlDatabase.ElasticScale.Client` is the official client library that allows ADO.NET developers to create applications that implement and use the pattern known as database sharding in Azure SQL Database. But it supports `.NET Standard 2.0` and `.NET Framework 4.5.0`.

Elastic Database features are composed of **Elastic Database client library, Elastic Database split-merge tool, Elastic Database jobs, Elastic Database query and Elastic transactions**.

Refer [Elastic Database client library with Entity Framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/elastic-scale-use-entity-framework-applications-visual-studio) for more details and sample code.

Comment: This does not answer the question asked.

Comment: How is this answer relevant to the question? Question is clearly for EF Core (.NET Core/5+).